# jquery "serialize" and "formSerialize" do not serialize options added to select element at client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms, http-post

```
var d = $('form[name=aspnetForm]').formSerialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: d
});
```

I have a ListBox with multiple selection to which options are added at the client side dynamically. The ListBox:-

```
 <select size="4" name="sel" multiple="multiple" id="sel">
```

I get every element in the form except the ListBox.Items.Count is Zero.

How can I serialize the ListBox along with other fields even if none of the Options is selected(I want to serialize every option in this ListBox, so that every options added at client side are available at server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write custom code to serialize all options - One of the way is to do create a simple js object with text & value for each list option and then convert this array to string uing JSON serialization. You can pass this JSON string to server via hidden field. On server side, you have JSON serializers (JavascriptSerializer, DataContractSerializer) that you can use to parse your options data.

Comment: thanks, actually I know this method, but I wanted to know if there is some other method e.g. Could I convert it into a format which is actually used for ListBox POST data originally had the options not been added at the client side. So that, I do not have to parse manually at the server and populate the ListBox Items.

Comment: @Puneet, POST data for html `select` will contain only values (that too selected one), text won't be sent. So what you wish is simply not possible! You have to send the needed data back to server.